# Unable to get all Matching string from NSDictionary iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I am new to iOS and little weak in logic.

Can any one help me here,

I want to get all matching data from NSDictionary.

eg:

my `tempDict` is NSDictionary which contains this,

tempDict:

```
errorCode = 00;
errorMessage = "<null>";
pastConsultations =     (

            {
        date = "16 December 2016";
        day = Friday;
        doctorName = "<null>";
        localTime = "07:30 AM";
        symptoms = q;
        today = Yes;
    },
            {
        date = "16 December 2016";
        day = Friday;
        doctorName = "<null>";
        localTime = "07:30 AM";
        symptoms = g;
        today = Yes;
    },
            {
        date = "13 December 2016";
        day = Tuesday;
        doctorName = "<null>";
        localTime = "12:30 PM";
        symptoms = fever;
        today = No;
    }
);
upcomingConsultations =     (
            {
        date = "16 December 2016";
        day = Friday;
        localTime = "09:30 PM";
        symptoms = "";
        today = Yes;
    },
            {
        date = "16 December 2016";
        day = Friday;
        localTime = "09:30 PM";
        symptoms = chj;
        today = Yes;
    },
            {
        date = "18 December 2016";
        day = Sunday;
        localTime = "12:30 PM";
        symptoms = "test an incoming ";
        today = No;
    }
);
}
```

Inside a `pastConsultations` key i want to get all nested data which contains `AM`

i.e my output should be:

```
{ //Array at 0th index
            date = "16 December 2016";
            day = Friday;
            doctorName = "<null>";
            localTime = "07:30 AM";
            symptoms = q;
            today = Yes;
        },
                { //Array at 1st index
            date = "16 December 2016";
            day = Friday;
            doctorName = "<null>";
            localTime = "07:30 AM";
            symptoms = g;
            today = Yes;
        }
}
```

Here is the code i have tried but it is not working, please help where i am making mistake?

```
NSArray *allKeys;
        for (int i=0; i<[tempDict count]; i++) {
           allKeys = [[[tempDict valueForKey:@"upcomingConsultations"] objectAtIndex:i] allKeys];



            NSString *targetKey = nil;
            // NSArray *allKeys = [[tempDict valueForKeyPath:@"pastConsultations"] allKeys];
            for (int j = 0; j < [allKeys count]; ++j) {
                NSString *key = [allKeys objectAtIndex:i];
                NSString *obj = [[[tempDict valueForKey:@"upcomingConsultations"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:key];
                if ([obj rangeOfString:searchText].location != NSNotFound) { // searchedString is what you're looking for
                    targetKey = key;
                    NSLog(@"found match");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is there any error or you are not getting result?

Comment: not getting the result

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

assuming you already have tempDict dictionary loaded.

```
NSMutableArray *morningPastArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray *pastArray = [tempDict objectForKey:@"pastConsultations"];
for (int i=0;i<[pastArray count]; i++) {
  NSDictionary *eachPast = [pastArray objectAtIndex:i];
  NSString *time = [eachPast objectForKey:@"localTime"];
  if (![time rangeOfString:@"AM"].location == NSNotFound) {
    [morningPastArr addObject:eachPast];
  }
}

// finally you will have like what you need in morningPastArr.
```

EDIT:
If you want to combine search results, for example, results for AM entry and Friday only you can do like this:

```
NSMutableArray *morningAndFridayPastArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray *pastArray = [tempDict objectForKey:@"pastConsultations"];
for (int i=0;i<[pastArray count]; i++) {
  NSDictionary *eachPast = [pastArray objectAtIndex:i];
  NSString *time = [eachPast objectForKey:@"localTime"];
  NSString *day = [eachPast objectForKey:@"day"];
  if ((![time rangeOfString:@"AM"].location == NSNotFound)&&([day isEqualToString:@"Friday"])) {
    [morningAndFridayPastArr addObject:eachPast];
  }
}
```

Comment: Why to use loop? predicate is more efficient than that.

Comment: Yes I agree. Your code is more efficient. But I am not so professional like you. My code normally is easier to understand by newbies (like myself). I am sorry for writing long code.

Comment: This is working smoothly, i am new to iOS i don't know about predicate. can you say how do i achieve this using predicate?

Comment: Can i search through all keys inside `pastConsultations` instead of searching in `localTime` only?

Comment: I dont quite understand what you mean. If you're searching for particular thing, you can substitute the key with something else that you want - [eachPast objectForKey:@"date"]; then you can add the requirement for date also and use if statements to check for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSPredicate` for that as follows:

```
NSPredicate *predicate;
NSMutableArray *filteredData=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"localTime contains[c] %@",@"AM"];
//OR Use below predicate as suggested by Rishi
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"localTime ENDSWITH 'AM'"];

filteredData=[[[tempDict valueForKey:@"pastConsultations"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]] mutableCopy];
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: It returns Empty `filteredData `

Comment: Check the edited answer, also check if `tempDict` is not `nil`@Appledeveloper

Comment: I still gets `filteredData` as nil also checked `tempDict` is not nil

Comment: Try this

predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"localTime ENDSWITH ‘AM’”];